# Name of last category level for a post

Tags: categories

I want to show the last category level of a post

for example, I hav a post in category "Course -> resultat -> Trail"

I want to show just "trail"

Thanks if somenone can help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following. I've used `get_the_terms` so it is readily extendible to any taxonomy.

This will return an array of terms (event if it contains just one). For instance, the post may have terms a,b,c,d,e in the relationship:

```
a   >   b  >   c      (parent > child)
d   >   e
```

In which case the following will return (as an array) the terms `c` and `e`. Whereas with the structure

```
a   >   b  >    c  >  d   >   e      (parent > child)
```

It will return an array of one term - `e`.

```
//Get all terms associated with post in taxonomy 'category'
$terms = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(),'category');

//Get an array of their IDs
$term_ids = wp_list_pluck($terms,'term_id');

//Get array of parents - 0 is not a parent
$parents = array_filter(wp_list_pluck($terms,'parent'));

//Get array of IDs of terms which are not parents.
$term_ids_not_parents = array_diff($term_ids,  $parents);

//Get corresponding term objects
$terms_not_parents = array_intersect_key($terms,  $term_ids_not_parents);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you don't assign multiple categories to the posts.

```
$categories = get_the_category(); 
echo 'Post categories: ' . implode(', ', $categories);
```

or just

```
echo get_the_category_list( ', ' );
```

**Updated** according the first comment.

Comment: Yes but I have multiple category for same popst

Comment: Then you should write it in your question. Code updated.

Comment: The problem is that I don't want all the list, I just need the last level category

Answer (score 0):

this work for me

```
 $allCat = get_the_category();
 $lastCat = array_reverse($allCat);
 echo $lastCat[0]->name;
```

Comment: I'm not so sure that `get_the_category` orders them in parent-child order. I think it orders just by term ID.

Comment: as OP said :
Course > resultat > Trail

Comment: Yes, but I don't think that the last term in `$allCat` will necessarily be 'Trail'. I think the last term `$allCat` will be the term with the highest ID.

Comment: I will try it thanks, but I think, I will use a meta box, this fucntionnality is just to show the name, not for link