# Link To Child Category For A Post

Tags: categories, links, array

I'm trying to display a link to just the child category on a Wordpress post. For instance if the category for a post is parent > child I want to show a link to just the child category page.

I'm using code from here: [Name of last category level for a post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55890/name-of-last-category-level-for-a-post/)

It works perfectly but just prints the child category, how do I go about making it a link tot he child category?

```
 $allCat = get_the_category();
 $lastCat = array_reverse($allCat);
 echo $lastCat[0]->name;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use get_category_link() for that:

```
$allCat = get_the_category();
if( ! empty( $allCat ) ){
    $lastCat = array_reverse( $allCat );
    $last_cat_link = get_category_link( $lastCat[0] );
    if( ! is_wp_error( $last_cat_link ) ){
        echo '<a href="' . $last_cat_link . '">' . $lastCat[0]->name . '</a>';
    }
}
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_category_link/

Comment: I tried this and it shows the correct child category but the link goes to the post, not the category page. @freejack

Comment: I have updated the code as there was a typo in $lastCat variable. Also added extra checks to avoid errors!

Comment: That's perfect, thanks for your help!